Memory Allocation Failure in GridDB
I have been using GridDB as database for my application for a while now as it is renowned for its scalability, which is best suited for my application since it heavily relies on its bulk upload feature. However, I recently encountered a client request failure execution from GridDB, and I cannot identify the root cause since the application has been working flawlessly since the bulk upload feature launched in the application.
The snippet of the code for the feature is as follows:
var griddb = require('griddb-node-api');

(async () => {
    try {
        const factory = griddb.StoreFactory.getInstance();
        const store = factory.getStore({
            "host": '239.0.0.1',
            "port": 31999,
            "clusterName": "defaultCluster",
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "admin"
        });
    
        const loaderinfo = new griddb.ContainerInfo({
            'name': "LoaderBooking",
            'columnInfoList': [
                ["user_id", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
                ["username", griddb.Type.STRING],
                ["email_id", griddb.Type.STRING],
                ["login_time", griddb.Type.TIMESTAMP],
                ["elapsed_time", griddb.Type.TIMESTAMP],
                ["logout_time", griddb.Type.TIMESTAMP],
                ["starting_location", griddb.Type.STRING],
                ["ending_location", griddb.Type.STRING],
                ["distance_travelled", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
                ["time_for_travel", griddb.Type.DOUBLE]
            ],
            'type': griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, 'rowKey': true
        });

        const container = await store.putContainer(loaderinfo);

        const insert_rows = [];

        for (let i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
            insert_rows.push([
                i,
                `User${i}`,
                `user${i}@gmail.com`,
                new Date(),
                new Date(),
                new Date(),
                "New York",
                "Allentown",
                149.67,
                107.42
            ]);
        }
        await container.multiPut(insert_rows);
        
        console.log("Loader data insert complete.");
        } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
})();

...

The code generates the following error in the log file as follows:
2024-07-06 15:30:45 ACLPTP48978 1120 [ERROR: 10039: TXN_ENCODE_FAILED] Execution of client request failed <VW5hYmxlIHRvIGFsbG9jYXRlIG1lbW9yeSBmb3IgdGhlIGJ1bGsgaW5zZXJ0IG9wZXJhdGlvbi4gQ2hlY2sgaWYgdGhlcmUgaXMgc3VmZmljaWVudCBtZW1vcnkgc3BhY2UgaW4gdGhlIHN5c3RlbS4=>

However, I have followed the documentation to increase the node and cluster size in both the definition files, gs_node.json and gs_cluster.json, but it did not help either. Has anyone encountered this error?
I appreciate any help you can provide.
